# Java - Socket.io emits but does not trigger listener

Tags: java, android, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have a socket that I am connecting to... Using the below library.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

I can connect to the socket, but when I emit a custom event `("addChannel")`, it never triggers my listener. but I can see on my server that it was a successful emit. [server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sCuQ.png)

I have tried various ways to fix this problem but it won't trigger my 'emit' listener. It should receive a JSON object.

Does somebody have any idea whats going wrong?

Note: using Java socket.io 1.0  and socket.io 2.0 on the server side.

Here is my code:

```
package com.apps.mazeyar.chatapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class Rooms extends AppCompatActivity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);
     final User user = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("USER");

     try {
         IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
         String[] transport = new String[1];
         transport[0] = "websocket";

         opts.transports = transport;
         opts.port = 443;
         opts.secure = true;
         opts.query = "s=" + user.getSessionId();

         Log.i("Socket:", "Connecting to socket: " + "on port:" + opts.port);

         final Socket socket = IO.socket("**************", opts);

         socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
             if (socket.connected()) {
                 Log.e("Socket", "Connected to socket");
                 socket.emit("addChannel", "10021237");
                 socket.on("addChannel", addChannel);
             } else {
                 Log.e("Socket:", "No connection");
             }
         });

         socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, args -> Log.e("Socket:", "Disconnected"));

         socket.connect();
     } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 private Emitter.Listener addChannel = new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(final Object...args) {
         Rooms.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                 Log.e("Callback", "is never called");
             }
         });
     }
 };
}
```